# PHP - How safe/strong is this hashing?

Tags: php, hash

So I am trying to "create" a strong hashing algoritme, and now I am wondering, how strong is it?

This is what I have came up with:

```
function bHash($text, $salt)
{
  foreach (array_reverse(hash_algos()) as $hash) {
    $hash .= hash($hash, $text . $hash . $salt);
   }

  return "_bH/" . $salt . "/" . str_replace("/", "+", crypt($hash, $salt));
}

echo bHash($password, "KB8NtFIN"); // I am using a different salt for each password!
```

So I am taking each hashing in the hash() function, and I hash it over and over again with salt (8 random string+hashname)

Which results in, for example "hello" is: `_bH/KB8NtFIN/KBumi3+cVUUtU`

So, how safe/strong is this?

Comment: Just 1 question: why are you doing this?

Comment: @Naruto I am just wondering how safe can I make password storing, without the use of already strong things like bCrypt

Comment: This is actually a very complex question which I doubt a lot of people can answer thoroughly or right, for that matter. If you're doing this for the hell of it, then good for you, if you're planning on using this in production then don't. But, if you're curios as to WHY you shouldn't write your own, have a look [here](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own).

Comment: @Matthew Not very safe. There are people who know a lot more about cryptography than you. It's better to just use what they have given us. Unless you're studying cryptography I wouldn't bother with this exercise.

Comment: @Clint why is it not safe?

Comment: If you compare the hash and the hashed password then, how do you know which salt to use?

Comment: @Matthew this is purely for educational reasons, right? Asking because somone might go out of their way to just talk you out of doing this - but may spend more time actually answering if they know you just want to learn.

Comment: @aleksv When for example logging in I can check the hash, grab the salt out of it and check it

Comment: @JimL Yes, it is just for educational reasons

Comment: Matthew, you would probably do well to read [this entire post from Security StackExchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords)

Comment: I suspect a few issues.  One, does every system produce the same number and order of hash_algos?  If not, this could be a disaster when trying to validate hashes from another system.  Secondly, I expect this to be slower and less secure as you're running through several weak hashing algorithms vs one that is known to be strong.

Comment: Consider that the currently accepted methods have been seriously peer reviewed. A do-it-yourself solution just can't meet that level of security. Consider  ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): "Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break."

Comment: Why go through all that trouble when there is password_hash() or the compatibility pack to work with. Plus, why mess around with salts?

Comment: @Fred-ii- it seems to be an educational assignment, and we know that educational establishments are the last places to keep themselves up to date with IT best practises :-/

Comment: "How strong is this hash?" - Compared to what? Compared to not hashing it is very strong :)

Comment: @Martin If it is, then it's purely academic. What they don't teach in schools is what's happening out in the "real world" and during "this century".

Comment: @Matthew I suggest you read these two blog posts from the author of the password compatibility layer. [Seven Ways To Screw Up BCrypt](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/12/seven-ways-to-screw-up-bcrypt.html) and [Security Issue: Combining Bcrypt With Other Hash Functions](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2015/03/security-issue-combining-bcrypt-with.html). They may give valuable insight into how easy it is to mess up even an audited/approved hash algo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> PHP - How safe/strong is this hashing?

Short Answer: not very.

Longer short answer: It isn't very strong compared to industry standards such as PGP or varios bCrypt implementations.

Longer answer: I don't want to rip off the answers provided [in this Security StackExchange Post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) but please, read that link, read these very long and very detailed answers as to the numerous and various pitfalls of your own hashing algorithm.

- Obfuscation is ***not*** hashing, just because you can't read it doesn't mean no one else can.
- As Zaph mentioned, [Schneiers Law](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html) is a relevant issue here.
- If you change the salt every time, what is the point of having the salt at all? The salt needs to be recognisable by the algorithm, take a very simple example: You have algebra which states `a = b + c` . The minimum number of equations you can use to find value of `a` is the number of unknown variables. So in this case 2 (one for `b` and one for `c`), so if you have `hash = salt + password` if you only then have one equation (the hash) you can't find *both* the salt and the password values from within the hash...
- what if your salt contains the `/` character? What if your password contains the `/` character?

P.s> Also the links to IRCMaxwells stuff posted by JimL are well worth reading too.